# Iterating and checking model field values, QuerySets

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to iterate through all of my Task model objects and check whether they have employees attached to them. If they do have employees attached, then I want to cycle through the manytomany relation between projects and users and get each associated users email address. I am having difficulty accessing the email field. It keeps giving me 'not iterable' or "global name 'users__type' is not defined," depending on what I change. Am I missing something simple if my end result intended to be a string of user emails.

Models

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True)
   type = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
   email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

*//Plus Other Custom User Fields//*

```
class Task(models.Model):
   users = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, blank=True, null=true)
```

*//Plus Other Task Fields//*

My other class

```
from django.models import Task
from django.models import CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import User   

def emailTaskList():
   chosenPeople = []
   notchosenPeople = []

   chosenTask = Task.objects.filter(users__type = 'employee')
   for e in chosen:
       for d in e.users.all():
           chosenPeople.append(d.email)
   notchosenTask = Task.objects.filter(users__type != 'employee')
   for a in notchosen:
      for b in a.users.all():
           notchosenPeople.append(b.email)

   test = ' '.join(chosenPeople)

   connection = mail.get_connection()
   email = mail.EmailMessage('You have been assigned', test, [WebsiteEmail], [testRecipient])
   email.send()
   connection.close()
   return
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you missed a comma ``test = ', '.join(chosenPeople)``

Comment: Also don't use camel case for vars, functions and methods in Python ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `exclude()` method instead of `!=` comparison:

```
notchosen = Task.objects.exclude(users__type='employee')
```

Comment: That did it, I didn't expect it to be so picky and 'users__type' is not defined does not seem like it would be that. Thank you

Comment: `users__type='employee'` is the passing of `users__type` keyword argument to the function. `users__type != 'employee'` is the comparing of `users__type` variable with a string and passing the boolean result into the function.  That is why python tries to find the `users__type` var.